# Toggle silent mode with automation in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, automation, sound-volume, shortcuts-app

Is it possible to enable/disable Silent mode using Automation in Shortcuts on iPhone?

If not, is it possible to detect the position of the silent rocker switch?

I am not interested in toggling DND for this scenario.

Comment: Silent mode is controlled by the rocker switch, AFAIK you can‘t toggle that with software.

Comment: you could use a concentration mode to do equivalent. You can also create a shortcut that put sound level to 0%

Comment: Focus is the same as DND, which the OP does not want to use.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is now possible to detect the volume of the device using Automation:

1. Add action
2. Select ‘If’
3. Select ‘Device Details’
4. Click ‘Device Details’
5. Select ‘Volume’
6. Select ‘Greater than or equal to’
7. Type a number in the range of 0.00-1.00, for example 0.07 is the first notch on the volume bar

However it seems like it is still not possible to check whether the silent rocker switch is on.

Comment: I understand that this somehow relates to the question you asked, it doesn't seem to actually answer the question though (which was about enabling/disabling silent mode). Maybe this would be better suited as an edit to the question, or as an answer to a yet to be written question?

Comment: @nohillside It's the closest thing I can find to detecting the silent rocker switch's position. I'm having to put my phone to 10% volume instead of using the silent rocker, as a workaround. If a better solution exists I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this isn't possible without jailbreaking. Could I know your use case and see if a clever implementation of DND could work?

Answer (score 0):

For future views of this question, it is possible in iOS 17 on a device that has a button instead of the switch style silence control. I believe the switch style control is why it was not possible before (conjecture).

In your shortcut or automation, just search for ‘silence mode’ and toggle if it should turn on or off.